# MySQL crashes on Windows boot

Tags: windows-8.1, mysql

Migrated from Stackoverflow

My setup is the following:

- Windows 8.1 Pro OS
- Main HDD 500GB split in two partitions (`C:` and `D:`), in order to be formatted without losing data
- Both partitions `BitLocker`-ed
- MySQL data dir under `D:/Mysql/Data`

I have the following symptoms: when PC boots after a hot shutdown (i.e. kernel session hibernated, user session shut down) or a complete cold reboot (i.e. rebooting kernel too) MySQL will start as service and respond.

However it will crash systematically on the first query(es). E.g. I can start my MySQL-based web application however the DBMS will crash after a few seconds. Same if I run queries directly.

I have to either stop&restart MySQL from console, **or** disable DBMS autostart and run `net start mysql56` after boot.

Setting `delayed start` does not help. I must start manually when the desktop is fully responsive.

#### How can I investigate this problem?

I have tried to look at the logs but...

```
2015-10-12 08:47:07 3776 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-10-12 08:47:07 3776 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-10-12 08:47:07 3776 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-10-12 08:47:07 3776 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-10-12 08:47:09 3776 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-10-12 08:47:09 3776 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.22-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Began my work day at 8:47 AM

```
2015-10-14 10:53:44 5744 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-10-14 10:53:44 5744 [Warning] The option innodb (skip-innodb) is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
2015-10-14 10:53:44 1c94 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-10-14 10:53:44 5744 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-10-14 10:53:44 5744 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-10-14 10:53:44 5744 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
```

No other log before first crash now at 10:53 AM

System logs do not show anything particular

Answer (score 0):

Good to check my.ini file.

First what I suggest to check - check current warning level
set it to **log-warnings=2** (or bigger)
this can give more information in error.log it help if crash happens by of MySQL internal reasons.

If MySQL crash as Windows program - log still will empty, because from MySQL view no errors.
In this case - migrating/upgrade to 5.6.27 not warrant, but may also resolve the problem, just because it little more new.

For check this - You can download zip version of MySQL (without installer) and run it manually (not as service)